# MySQL dynamic replace capitalize

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a way to find, replace and capatilize some text in a MySQL table.

Text to replace:

```
/source/data-list/new-items/list.php
```

Replace with:

```
/source/data-list/new-items/Data-List_New-Items_CustomText.zip
```

First (`source`) and last part of the text `list.php` is same for all occurrences but `data-list/new-items part` is different.

I want to replace `list.php` with text from `data-list/new-item + Customtext.zip` and capatilize first letter of each word.

Before replace:

```
/source/data-list/new-items/list.php
/source/datas/old-items/list.php
/source/data-list/fresh/list.php
```

After replace:

```
/source/data-list/new-items/Data-List_New-Items_CustomText.zip
/source/datas/old-items/Datas_Old-Items_CustomText.zip
/source/data-list/fresh/Data-List_Fresh_CustomText.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

You can capitalize a string in MySQL with

```
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(`columnname`, 1)), SUBSTRING(`columnname`, 2))
```